# ¿Cómo colocar dos registros consecutivos de una tabla en dos filas de una consulta SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente tabla con los registros

| name | id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VENEZUELA | 1 | 16 |
| COCACOLA | 2 | 16 |
| MEXICO | 3 | 45 |
| FACEBOOK | 4 | 45 |

Como ven el user_id está repetido porque el primer registro de ese usuario es su pais y el segundo es la marca. Yo quisiera traer una consulta así.

| id | nombreDelPais | nombreDeLaMarca |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | VENEZUELA | COCACOLA |
| 45 | MEXICO | FACEBOOK |

Este es mi SQL. Porfavor ayúdenme.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tabla1.name as companyname, tabla2.name as country FROM users
INNER JOIN tabla1 as tabla1 ON users.id = tabla1.user_id
INNER JOIN tabla1 as tabla2 ON users.id = tabla2.user_id
```

Comment: Bienvenido JoseAngelDev a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿No tienes ninguna codificación o tipo que diga que una fila corresponde al país y la otra a la marca? Y define correctamente el motor ¿mysql o sqlserver?

Comment: Me parece que tus tablas no estan correctamente normalizadas